# Static and Generic working together .NET

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, static, generics

I have this code:

```
public class EntityMapper<T> where T : IMappingStrategy, new()
{
    private static T currentStrategy;

    public static T CurrentStrategy  
    {
        get
        {
            if (currentStrategy == null)
                currentStrategy = new T();

            return currentStrategy;
        }
    }


}
```

Then:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        EntityMapper<ServerMappingStrategy>.CurrentStrategy.ToString();
        EntityMapper<ClientMappingStrategy>.CurrentStrategy.ToString();
        EntityMapper<ServerMappingStrategy>.CurrentStrategy.ToString();
    }
```

Well, the question is:

Why when i'm debugging i can see that the constructor of ServerBussinessMappingStrategy is called only once time?

This work well, but i undertand why always EntityMapper return the correct instance that i need, only instantiating once time the ServerMappingStrategy class.

Regards!

PD: Sorry my english jeje ;)

Answer (score 5):

The `static` field is persisted for the duration of your `AppDomain`, and it is cached when first created:

```
public static T CurrentStrategy  
{
    get
    {
        if (currentStrategy == null) // <====== first use detected
            currentStrategy = new T(); // <==== so create new and cache it

        return currentStrategy; // <=========== return cached value
    }
}
```

Actually, there is an edge case when it could run twice (or more), but it is unlikely.

This is a pretty common pattern for deferred initialization, and is used pretty much identically in a number of places in the BCL. Note that if it had to happen **at most** once, it would need either synchronization (`lock` etc) or something like a nested class with a static initializer.

Comment: The synchronization issue is why the best practice is to initialize it in the declaration.  Jon Skeet goes into this in much more detail here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it will only get called once. That is, unless you have a race condition.

Let's say two threads execute this statement the same time:

```
EntityMapper<ServerMappingStrategy>.CurrentStrategy.ToString();
```

Let's say **thread A** will run up until `currentStrategy == null` but gets paused before `new T()` when Windows suddenly gives control to **thread B** which then makes the comparison again, `currentStrategy` is still null, invokes the constructor and assigns the new instance to `currentStrategy`. Then, at some point, Windows gives the control back to **thread A** that calls the constructor again. This is important because normally static members are (sort of) expected to be thread safe. So if I were you, I would wrap that bit into a `lock` clause.

P.S. this snippet won't compile as T might be a struct that cannot be a null. Instead of comparing to null, compare to default(T) or specify that T has to be a class.